# Android Studio error while installing app into a device

Tags: java, android

Can someone help me please I can't install my app when I try to install it it says:

> AndroidStudioProjects\2\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_split_apk_resources\debug\instantRunSplitApkResourcesDebug\out\slice_6\resources_ap

Any help?!

Comment: disable instant run then reinstall the app.

Comment: thank you so much it actually worked please wright that as an answer so others can know that info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable instant run then reinstall the app.
It should work.